# powershell backup script with error logging per file

Tags: powershell, backup

Really need help creating a script that backs up, and shoots out the error along the file that did not copy

Here is what I tried:

Creating lists of filepaths to pass on to `copy-item`, in hopes to later catch errors per file, and later log them:

by using `$list2X` I would be able to cycle through each file, but `copy-item` loses the Directory structure and shoots it all out to a single folder.
So for now I am using `$list2` and later I do `copy-item -recurse` to copy the folders:

```
#create list to copy
$list = Get-ChildItem -path $source | Select-Object Fullname
$list2 = $list -replace ("}"),("")
$list2 = $list2 -replace ("@{Fullname=") , ("")

out-file -FilePath g:\backuplog\DirList.txt -InputObject $list2

#create list crosscheck later
$listX = Get-ChildItem -path $source -recurse | Select-Object Fullname
$list2X = $listX -replace ("}"),("")
$list2X = $list2X -replace ("@{Fullname=") , ("")

out-file -FilePath g:\backuplog\FileDirList.txt -InputObject $list2X
```

And here I would pass the list:

```
$error.clear()
Foreach($item in $list2){
 Copy-Item -Path $item -Destination $destination -recurse -force -erroraction Continue 
  }
 out-file -FilePath g:\backuplog\errorsBackup.txt -InputObject $error
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to complex file-copying or backup scripts is almost always: "Use robocopy."

Bill

Comment: Thx for the answer Bill, i will be looking at it this weekend, cause for the moment im too backed up with my schooling.                    I read a lil about robocopy, hope it stands with the logging options im looking for! thx again

Answer (score 0):

"[Want to copy all the items in C:\Scripts (including subfolders) to C:\Test? Then simply use a wildcard character...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156818.aspx)"

Next make it easier on yourself and do something like this:

```
$files = (Get-ChildItem $path).FullName #Requires PS 3.0
#or
$files = Get-ChildItem $path | % {$_.Fullname}
$files | Out-File $outpath
```

Answer (score 0):

well it took me a long time, considering my response time. here is my copy function, which logs most errors(network drops, failed copies , etc) the copy function , and targetobject.

```
Function backUP{ Param ([string]$destination1 ,$list1)
$destination2 = $destination1
                          #extract new made string for backuplog
                        $index = $destination2.LastIndexOf("\") 
                        $count = $destination2.length - $index
                        $source1 = $destination2.Substring($index, $count)
                        $finalstr2 = $logdrive + $source1

Foreach($item in $list1){

 Copy-Item -Container: $true -Recurse -Force -Path $item -Destination     $destination1     -erroraction Continue 
 if(-not $?)
 {
  write-output "ERROR de copiado : " $error| format-list | out-file  -Append             "$finalstr2\GCI-ERRORS-backup.txt"
      Foreach($erritem in $error){
      write-output "Error Data:" $erritem.TargetObject  | out-file -Append   "$finalstr2\GCI-    ERRORS-backup.txt"
          }
  $error.Clear()
     }
   }
 }
```